# Are the flag and close popups out of place?

Tags: bug, status-completed

It appears the the popups for flag and close have moved and are no longer centered on the main site (possibly due to hats). On meta, they popup centered in the viewport, on the main, they are pushed down and to the right and sometimes off the screen.

Tested this in Chrome (16) and IE (9).

Example of a full screen shot (just picked one, not closing or flagging it for any reason):
[image]

Comment: I notice this on Safari 5.1.2 running on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: Yep, that should be the hats' fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this was caused by the hat change, it was really a bug in the standard "center this on the screen" code that only handled trivial situations – and the hats created a non-trivial one. Fixed in the next build.