# What are hats?

Tags: support, winterbash

I've just seen a kind of red link on gaming site.

It's toggle between `I love hats` and  `I hate hats`.

The toggle button-link is on bottom page and red.

What is it ?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I noticed that the header was modified but I didn't notice that's written `hat dash`. I clicked on the image and discovered a new world! But the princess in an another castle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://hatdash.com/) should explain everything you want to know.  From the related [blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/):

> For three weeks, decorate your gaming.stackexchange.com gravatar with
>   custom hats:
>
> - Unlock game-themed hats for asking and answering questions about top holiday games
> - Get special hats for reaching the rep cap, voting, earning or giving a bounty, or participating on meta and chat
> - Earn the coveted user-of-the-day crown for being the most upvoted user
> - …and much, much more!  Over 20 hats in all!

This button lets you opt out from the hat 'experience' - perhaps you don't like it, or [it screws up the page too hard.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3508/are-the-flag-and-close-popups-out-of-place)

Answer (score 7):

The Gaming site is currently in an event, called [Hat Dash](http://hatdash.com/).  Basically, what happens here, is users can earn hats for their Gravatars by being active on the site.  Saying 'I hate hats' just disables them for you.  You jerk.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the [Holiday 2011 Hat Dash](http://hatdash.com/).

Basically, doing certain things around the site, including posting on Meta and chatting, will award you with hats in your profile.

Once you have a hat, you can go to your profile to change hats.

There are [30 regular hats](http://hatdash.com/#hats) and [6 secret hats](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/what-secret-hats-are-there) (technically 7, but everyone has the "Invisible hat" one).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to [read the announcement on the blog](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) about our holiday season event.

There's also a [microsite](http://hatdash.com) associated with this event, and we even [created a chat room for the event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2013/hats-hats-hats-hats) to keep our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) from being spammed.